# c# how DataContractSerializer is able to overcome on private setters?

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer, private-members

I have class with property named ID and its' setter is private. I can not understand how DataContractSerializer is able to deserialize the stream correctly as setter is private?

```
    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    [KnownType(typeof(FormElementBase))]
    [KnownType(typeof(FormDataElementBase))]
    [KnownType(typeof(FormElementGroupBase))]
    [KnownType(typeof(BoxGroup))]
    [KnownType(typeof(PanelGroup))]
    [KnownType(typeof(PageGroup))]
    [KnownType(typeof(PageGroupContainer))]
    public abstract class ApplicationDomainItemBase 
    {
        protected ApplicationDomainItemBase()
        {

        }

        protected ApplicationDomainItemBase(int id) : this(id, "", "")
        {

        }

        protected ApplicationDomainItemBase(int id, string name, string description)
        {
            _ID = id;
            _Name = name;
            _Description = description;
        }

        [DataMember]
        private int _ID;

        [DataMember]
        public int ID
        {
            get { return _ID; }
            private set
            { }
        }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Reflection is the magic part

Comment: But the private setter is useless, it only matters what is written into the private field (also decalred as DataMember)

Comment: Yes, I missed that there is DataMember attribute on _ID. Thanks.